# Why isn't an error being displayed?

Tags: php

So I'm in the process of connecting to a database. And here's my index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
require_once 'core/init.php';
DB::getInstance();
?>
```

Followed by my `init.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '*',
    'db' => 's'
    ), 
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => '604800'

    ),
'session' => array(
'session_name' => 'user' 
));

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
require_once 'classes/'. $class.'.php';

});
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

?>
```

Then followed by my  DB.php

```
<?php
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query, 
        $_error = false, 
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;


private function __constuct(){
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}       
public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;

}
}
```

Why is it that when I enter invalid credentials I don't get an error? I'm working off of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_alwb6Twiw&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc) video.

Comment: sidenode: your `getInstance()` method should return the instance, not just create it.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Not getting anything @AdrianPreuss

Comment: Just returned it and nothing is showing up still. @dognose

Comment: @user302975 it was not about your problem - just a sidenode. Are you using IIS or Apache?

Comment: Oh a sidenote. I'm using Apache @dognose

Comment: Try to set the error-handling over `.htaccess` > `php_flag display_errors On`, Depending on how PHP is installed and configured, you can't set that via `ini_set();`

Comment: Otherwise, checkout your errorlogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your Constructor `__construct`, not `__constuct` :-)

Comment: That then shows me the credentials. Not tell me if the connection is successful...

Comment: @user302975 But now your Constructor is invoked, stating "login denied". You are creating a config array, but accessing the values, as if they are static class members. Try it with passing the login directly (`$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',"root","anyPassword");`), then refactor your config-class (or array).

Comment: So what would that look like?

Comment: `$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',"root","anyPassword");`

Comment: Yes I know about that, but how would I do it with my array?

Comment: @user302975 Handling an array is nothing that needs to be discussed here. Search for proper usage. Plenty of examples out there.